# Как правильно: он — стонет, они — стонут, а я — ..?

Tags: синтаксис

Как правильно сказать? Стону? Стенаю?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Я стону**. Парадигма простая: *я стону, ты стонешь, он стонет, мы стонем, вы стонете, они стонут.*

Глагол **стенать** имеет другую парадигму: *я стенаю, ты стенаешь, он стенает, мы стенаем, вы стенаете, они стенают.*